# how to automate / script processes like signups 

Tags: javascript, vbscript, automation, selenium, autoit

which is the best tool for this -

Automation of signup process to a website , e.g an email signup

The tool should be able to take data from an external data file like an excel of csv file

this data file would contain data such as first name , last name , username, password etc. basic data required during an email signup . I am imagining the data file to contain of each 
field in a seperate column and each row to contain data for different registration / user.

At the places where manual intervention is required like image verification etc. the tool should be able to pause the script until manual bit is done then continue with the script.

What is the best way to do this - an automation tool , or any scripting language - please suggest .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) v3 is really made for this. I've once created an app to read excel file then use that data to populate other stuff I needed it to. It has well built commands to automate web including functions to control website (especially by using _IE functions). They also have great [forum](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/) and Help File which should get you up and running in to time. Also you can compile it to .exe which makes it nice for easy deployment to multiple users with no need to have external libraries. Everything can come embedded.

Comment: This is tailor fit to AutoIt.

Answer (score 1):

[TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) is quite good at website automation. There are many formats for inputting data, it depends on exactly what format is needed and how you intend on using it.  Usually writing a quick CSV conversion script is easier than using the CSV directly (though it can be done, and the conversion can be written in TestPlan as well).

It has its own scripting language which is usually sufficient for all uses. Java units are also available if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well go for [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)  to automate the sign up process. It can have the ability to interact with all kinds of HTML elments